# Is it possible to specify the SIZE of image requests from https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

When utilising Firebase Storage to store imagery, for example, user avatars, is there a way that you can request a ***smaller, thumbnail sized serving*** of the image?

I have searched Google and documentation and I have been unable to come up with a result. Currently my app utilising Firebase Storage URLs experiences a minor delay prior to loading images due to the fact that it I am requesting large images to fill tiny avatars.

Is there a resource I am overlooking that specifies the available parameters for this URL? (of which `token` & `alt` are two I'm aware of).

Thank you for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-resizing images upon read is **not** a feature of Firebase Storage. The typical solution is to create variants of the images during upload, for example through the [Resize Images extension](https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firebase-storage-resize-images).

Comment: Thanks Frank, I didn't even know extensions existed tbh. https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions for anyone else who wants to browse the options. Is this similar to an app store, could developers add extensions & garner revenue in future? +feature suggestion :P

Comment: One final question - the extension doesn't operate retroactively?

Comment: 1) There is no way to sell Extensions at the moment, as typically the services that they wrap are monetized already. Here for example, you'll be charged for the time the Cloud Functions spend performing the actual resizing. --- 2) The Extension indeed only processes images right after they are uploaded. It does not process existing images.

Comment: One last question @Frank van Puffelen, if I may; is it possible to retrieve the new `token` or alternatively set the token while uploading? It appears as though the metadata token is generated anew for each resize operation. In my case I have an app where someone is uploading their profile photo, it resizes a couple of times via the extension, but I have no ability to reference the generated thumbnails now without traversing the file storage manually. Given that tokens are required to access the files. Alternatively can tokenised access be disabled? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately ended up going back to manual resizing instead, to control tokens